# Relación de Tablas de Muchos a Muchos a Muchos (m:n:k) RELACIÓN TERNARIA SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hay bastante información de m a m, pero no consigo nada concreto que me ayude a entender esas complejas tablas donde hay una **Relación Ternaria (entre 3)**; Se que para estos casos se debe crear una tabla intermedia, algo así como la tabla hija de un trió.

Esta tabla deberá heredar los campos primarios de sus madres y convertir esos  campos primarios en un "campo primario compuesto" *(ayudenme con las definiciones en caso de estar equivocado, no estoy muy claro en el tema por eso hago la pregunta*) si es así veamos el siguiente ejemplo(*no esta completo*):

```
CREATE TABLE `taller_bdphp`.`t3_asignacion` (

        `idst3` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,    /*este seria el id para
                                                    identificar el registro, ejemplo: Registro numero: 203*/

         `placa` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,                 /*esto seria una FK y a 
                                                    su vez una PK de la tabla vehiculos*/

        `cedula_p` INT(8) NOT NULL ,                /*esto seria una FK y a 
                                                    su vez una PK de la tabla personal, 
                                                    sirve para indicar el mecánico que esta trabajando con el vehiculo y que servicio le realiza a su vez*/

        `idservicio` INT(3) NOT NULL ,              /*esto seria un FK y asu vez una PK de la tabla servicios, 
                                                    (existen determinados servicios, por ejemplo: Revision, Mantenimiento, Lavado.
                                                    y se le debe poder asignar uno o mas servicios al vehiculo.*/

         `fecha_iniciot3` DATE NOT NULL ,           /*esto seria un campo propio de la tabla ternaria,
                                                    indica la fecha en que se inicia el servicio asignado*/

        `fecha_fint3` DATE NULL ,                    /* otro campo que puede estar nulo,
                                                     indica la fecha que se termina el servicio (cuando el vehiculo se va)*/

        `Estadot3` VARCHAR(1000) NULL ,             /*otro campo simple para escribir o comentar sobre el estado del servicio*/

         PRIMARY KEY (`idst3`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

(Uff  me canse haciendo eso jeje..) espero que así lo puedan entender mejor.. Si comprendieron la tabla.. **NO esta COMPLETA los FK y la declaración de la "PRIMARY KEY COMPUESTA" NO ESTÁN HECHAS...Ahí mi pregunta: ¿Como se hace eso?**

- ¿Se tendría que colocar o declarar de nuevo los campos foráneos?
  ¿repetirlos es requerido? Aquí no se, porque como también son
  primarios no se como considerarlos en este caso...
- Por otra parte ¿luego de ahí como se declararía el "PRIMARY KEY COMPUESTA"?
   PRIMARY KEY (`idst3`,`placa`,`cedula_p`,`idservicio`)) <<< *¿esa seria la manera correcta?*
- ¿Por Ultimo como se declararían las claves foráneas, esas si siguen
  igual una por una con el mismo método de siempre?
  Bueno el método que yo uso es:

`FOREIGN KEY(placa) REFERENCES vehiculos(placa),`

es correcto ese método cierto? aunque hay gente que le Coloca un CONSTRAINT que nunca supe bien para que era porque aunque no se coloque igual funciona, ademas están los que agregan el

`ON DELETE CASDADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,` (para actualizar las tablas en "cascada" [si una se modifica se modifican las demás])
¡¿¿En phpmyadmin se colocan como index las que seran foraneas y parte de la primaria compuesta.. se debe elegir luego el crear indice de una sola columna o crear indice compuesto??!

Fuente de Referencia: https://www.genbetadev.com/bases-de-datos/bases-de-datos-y-relaciones-ternarias

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, no se si con esto quedaría claro, cuando creas una tabla fruto de una relación ternaria, la primary key y sus foreign key se declararían de este modo:

```
FOREIGN KEY (fk1) references tabla_padre1 (pk);
FOREIGN KEY (fk2) references tabla_padre2 (pk);
FOREIGN KEY (fk3) references tabla_padre3 (pk);
PRIMARY KEY (fk1,fk2,fk3);
```

Si añades las foreign key durante la creación de la tabla, no es forzosamente necesario añadir la palabra reservada `Constraint` (o restricción), si que lo es cuando añadimos la referencia de una clave foranea después de haber creado la tabla (puedes declarar la tabla y la primary key compuesta sin necesidad de indicar en ese momento que los tres campos son claves foraneas).
Espero que algo haya aclarado.
Respecto a cuando establecer una relación n:m:k, podemos suponer el caso en que para la gestión energética en una central nuclear, contamos con una entidad `Central Nuclear`, una entidad `Proveedor` (alguno de los suministradores de Uranio a la central) y una entidad `Transportista` (cualquiera de los camioneros que se dediquen a realizar el porte).

Si deseamos conocer de cada suministro de uranio quien es el `Proveedor`, qué `Transportista` realizar el porte y hacia qué `Central Nuclear` lo lleva, así como por ejemplo la cantidad del material que transporta, la única manera de recogerlo sería a través de una relación ternaria.
(Es posible que haya ejemplos más claros, este fue con el que yo mejor lo entendí).

Comment: Gracias Pablo! al confirmar la declaracion de las FK y PK, entoncs no estaba tan mal.. y  por aclarar lo del Constraint (restricciones.. interesante.. pero q tipo de restricciones da? algun ejemplo?) . No entendí muy bien esta parte: "puedes declarar la tabla y la PK compuesta sin necesidad de indicar en ese momento que los tres campos son claves foraneas" te refieres a q luego se puede usar ALTER TABLE para declararlas como FK? pero si obligatorio poner la PK compuesta cierto? ... ¿Haz hecho relaciones de este tipo por phpmyadmin? como colocaría los campos antes de crearle la FK, INDEX? ?

Comment: Exacto, puedes hacer un ''alter table add constraint...'' para añadir la foreign key, otras restricciones pueden ser delimitar un rango de valores para un campo (de 0 a 100 por ejemplo) o un conjunto especificado ('mujer','hombre').  Respecto a tu última pregunta, he usado alguna vez phpmyadmin, pero suelo trabajar mejor desde la consola, no se muy bien a que te refieres con colocar los campos, puedes ser más conciso?